# Linked List Stack

Tags: java, array, stack

I have no trouble with my code on working part but I still have some worries if there is something missing so I want a review for my code. Also, I wonder if the exceptions are true type for these methods.

```
public class ArrayListStack<E> implements Stack<E> {

    private ArrayList<E> list;

    public ArrayListStack()
    {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return list.size();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return size() == 0;
    }

    public void push(E e)
    {
        list.add(size(), e);
    }

    public E top()
    {
        if(isEmpty()) throw new IllegalStateException("Array is empty");
        return list.get(size()-1);
    }

    public E pop()
    {
        if(isEmpty()) throw new IllegalStateException("Array is empty");
        return list.remove(size()-1);
    }


}
```

Comment: Small nitpick: `list.add(size(), e);` can just be `list.add(e)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Error messages should not leak implementation details unnecessarily

`ArrayListStack` is an implementation of your custom interface `Stack`.
Presumably users would declare their stacks using the interface type, for example:

```
Stack<String> strings = new ArrayListStack<>();
```

The stack of strings may get passed to methods expecting a `Stack<String>`,
and then if `top` or `pop` get called when the stack is empty,
the exception message will say `"Array is empty"`,
which is an implementation detail.

Instead of throwing `new IllegalStateException("Array is empty")`,
you could do what the JDK implementation of [`Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) does,
and throw [EmptyStackException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EmptyStackException.html).
No need for a custom message,
it's already encapsulated in that exception.

You could get some other hints from the JDK's implementation,
such as the method names and return types.

#### Use `final` when possible

The `list` field can be marked `final`.
It's good to mark fields `final` when possible,
as these fields cannot be reassigned,
they are easier to read, understand, and trust.

You could also initialize the field on a single line,
and drop the explicit constructor:

```
private final List<E> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

#### Don't repeat yourself

This line appears twice in the code:

> ```
> if (isEmpty()) throw new IllegalStateException("Array is empty");
> ```

You could move this to a helper function, you could call it `ensureNonEmptyStack`.

#### Appending to a list

The 2-parameter version of `list.add` inserts an element at the specified position.
In your code, your intention is to append at the end of the list.
That's what the 1-parameter version of `list.add` does,
and it would be simpler and more appropriate in this code.

#### Formatting conventions in Java

The convention is to place opening braces on the same line as the statements.

Answer (score 0):

1. I tend to instantiate my collection as soon as possibile. Also, using `final` you are sure that nobody will set it to `null` (no need to null-check == code more readable and safer)

   `private final ArrayList<E> list = new ArrayList<>();`
2. Consider the use of `@Override` to mark overriden methods so future you (and other developers) understand the origin of your methods at glance.